# Can't send post data from ajax

Tags: ajax, function, post

I have game.php file have this text input which sending three values to javascript:

```
<script src="js/jq.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="textfield2" id="textfield2" onkeyup="home(this.value,<?php echo $uid ?>,<?php echo $row_g['id'] ?>)" />
```

the javascript is :

```
function home(homeex,uid,mid){
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
   url: "inuphome.php",
   data: { homeex: homeex, uid: uid, mid: mid },
   success: function (result) {
   }
});
}
```

inuphome.php file try to insert or update received data :

```
<?php 
require_once('connections/connect.php');

$homeex=$_POST['homeex'];
$uid=$_POST['uid'];
$mid=$_POST['mid'];

    $exp="SELECT * FROM expects Where uid='$uid' and mid='$mid'";
    $result_ex=mysqli_query($berikane,$exp);
    $row_ex=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_ex);
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($result_ex);

        if ($count==0){
        $query = "INSERT INTO expects  VALUES ('','$uid','$mid','$homeex','','')";  
        mysqli_query($berikane,$query); 
        }
        else{
        $query = "UPDATE expects SET homeex='$homeex' where uid='$uid' and mid='$mid'";
        }
?>
```

but nothing happens ,how can i solve this , best regards.

Comment: Did you look at your console for errors? You do nothing with the success method. You should add an error handler to the Ajax call. My guess there is an error message about some undefined varaible.

Comment: FYI: you are going to kill your server with making an Ajax call on every keypress.

Comment: What to advice to use instead of onupkey or ajax?